# Javascript not drawing in canvas properly in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, canvas, touchscreen, mobile-devices

Please help me with the problem I'm having. I'm trying to create a canvas to save signature as byte image. It works fine from my PC. but when I browse it on my iPhone, it draws at the bottom of the corner rather than from the top of the corner.Here's my code:

```
function signatureCapture() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("txtSignature");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 276;
    canvas.height = 180;
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.strokeStyle = "#444";
    context.lineWidth = 1.5;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var disableSave = true;
    var pixels = [];
    var cpixels = [];
    var xyLast = {};
    var xyAddLast = {};
    var calculate = false;
    {   //functions
        function remove_event_listeners() {
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

            document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
        }

        function get_coords(e) {
            var x, y;

            if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
                var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
                var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;

                x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
                y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;


            } else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
                x = e.layerX;
                y = e.layerY;
            } else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
            }

            return {
                x : x,
                y : y
            };
        };

        function on_mousedown(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

            empty = false;
            var xy = get_coords(e);
            context.beginPath();
            pixels.push('moveStart');
            context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
            pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
            xyLast = xy;
        };

        function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var xy = get_coords(e);
            var xyAdd = {
                x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
                y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
            };

            if (calculate) {
                var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
                var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
                pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
            } else {
                calculate = true;
            }

            context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            xyAddLast = xyAdd;
            xyLast = xy;

        };

        function on_mouseup(e) {
            remove_event_listeners();
            disableSave = false;
            context.stroke();
            pixels.push('e');
            calculate = false;
        };
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4whews1r/ Tested on iOS, Android, and Windows (PC), with touchscreen and mouse, all working fine.

Comment: Thanks, it was div that was preventing me from having the desired result.